# How is it possible that updating a numpy array derived from a Pandas DatFrame column also (unexpectedly) updates the data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Stumbled across this oddity while debugging, updating a numpy array derived from a Pandas Dataframe column also unexpectedly modifies the values of the Dataframe, although it was never referenced in the update, only the numpy array is mentioned. How is this possible?

```
    import numpy as np

    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A"],data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

    xarray = df1.iloc[:,0].values #put df1 values into an np array

    for i in range (0,len(xarray)): #change some of the np array values

        if xarray[i] >5:

          xarray[i] = 0

    df1.head(10) #but why are the dateframe values also getting updated ?? df1 rows with values>5 also get zero'd


A
```

0   1

1   2

2   3

3   4

4   5

5   0

6   0

7   0

8   0

9   0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) returns a view of the data (rather than a copy) if the columns are all of the same type. Since you only have one column, you actually have a reference to the data, so modifying it will modify the source dataframe.

To ensure you have a copy, use the copy argument of [`pd.DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy), e.g. `df.to_numpy(copy=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of the data:

```
xarray = df1.iloc[:,0].copy()
```